# What version of Drush is compatible with Drupal 6 / PHP 5.2

Tags: 6, drush

Just installed drush on a system using PHP 5.2.  However, when I run drush, a message is displayed saying `Your command line PHP installation is too old. Drush requires atleast PHP 5.3.0. To suppress this check, set the environment variable
DRUSH_NO_MIN_PHP=1`.  Since I am using Drupal 6 I need to use PHP 5.2. Could someone please tell me which version of Drush is compatible with Drupal6 / PHP5.2.

Answer (score 1):

A list of Drush versions and their compatibility can be found [here](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/). Appears Drush Version 5.x is compatible with php5.2.

Here is the current compatibility table reproduced from the link above

[image]